# I can't migrate another table which links with other table columns

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, migration

I am learning Laravel 8 and came across this problem, I made 4 migrations and their models. When I ran the command `php artisan migrate`, a problem comes up in the last migration.

**This is the 1st migration** (2021_08_18_092502_create_masyarakats_table.php)

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMasyarakatsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('masyarakat', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // Data akun masyarakat
            $table->char('nik', 16)->primary();
            $table->string('nama', 35);
            $table->string('username', 25)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('telp', 13);

            // Rekam tanggal
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('masyarakat');
    }
}
```

**This is the 2nd migration** (2021_08_18_093833_create_pengaduans_table.php)

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePengaduansTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pengaduan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // Data laporan pengaduan
            $table->id('id_pengaduan', 11);
            $table->dateTime('tgl_pengaduan');
            $table->char('nik', 16);
            $table->text('isi_laporan');
            $table->string('foto');
            $table->enum('status',['0', 'proses', 'selesai']);

            // Rekam tanggal
            $table->timestamps();

            // Menghubungkan kolom
            $table->foreign('nik')->references('nik')->on('masyarakat');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pengaduan');
    }
}
```

**This is the 3rd migration** (2021_08_19_002414_create_petugas_table.php)

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePetugasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('petugas', function (Blueprint $table) {
           // Data akun petugas
           $table->id('id_petugas', 11);
           $table->string('nama_petugas', 35);
           $table->string('username', 25)->unique();
           $table->string('password');
           $table->string('telp', 13);
           $table->enum('level', ['admin', 'selesai']);

           // Rekam tanggal
           $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('petugas');
    }
}
```

**This is the 4th migration** (2021_08_19_003445_create_tanggapans_table.php)

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateTanggapansTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tanggapan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // Data tanggapan laporan
           $table->id('id_tanggapan', 11)->primary();
           $table->integer('id_pengaduan', 11);
           $table->dateTime('tgl_tanggapan');
           $table->text('isi_tanggapan');
           $table->integer('id_petugas', 11);

           // Rekam tanggal
           $table->timestamps();

           // Menghubungkan kolom
           $table->foreign('id_pengaduan')->references('id_pengaduan')->on('pengaduan');
           $table->foreign('id_petugas')->references('id_petugas')->on('petugas');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tanggapan');
    }
}
```

***And for the model.***
**This is the 1st model** (masyarakat.php)

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class masyarakat extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'masyarakat';

    protected $primaryKey = 'nik';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nik',
        'nama',
        'username',
        'password',
        'telp',
    ];
}
```

**This is the 2nd model** (pengaduan.php)

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class pengaduan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'pengaduan';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_pengaduan';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_pengaduan',
        'tgl_pengaduan',
        'isi_laporan',
        'nik',
        'status',
        'foto',
    ];
}
```

**This is the 3rd model** (petugas.php)

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class petugas extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'petugas';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_petugas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_pengaduan',
        'nama_petugas',
        'username',
        'password',
        'level',
        'telp',
    ];
}
```

**This is the 4th model** (tanggapan.php)

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tanggapan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'tanggapan';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_tanggapan';

    protected $fillable = [
        'tgl_pengaduan',
        'isi_tanggapan',
        'id_pengaduan',
        'id_tanggapan',
    ];
}
```

I got this problem, the first-third migration table was successfully created but the fourth table failed.

The terminal output when i migrate

```
Migrating: 2021_08_19_003445_create_tanggapans_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only 
one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: create table `tanggapan` (`id_tanggapan` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `id_pengaduan` int not null auto_increment primary key, `tgl_tanggapan` datetime not null, `isi_tanggapan` text not null, `id_petugas` int not null auto_increment primary key, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at D:\Docs\Sekolah\project_ukk_apriza\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error       
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }

  1   D:\Docs\Sekolah\project_ukk_apriza\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key")

  2   D:\Docs\Sekolah\project_ukk_apriza\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `primary` should be `primary()`. It would help if you add the actual error you got.

Comment: Thank you @P.K.Tharindu I forgot that. But the problem is not there, I have edited the question, maybe you can help.

Answer (score 0):

The `id()` method is an alias of the `bigIncrements` method. So try using `unsignedBigInteger()` for `id_pengaduan` and `id_petugas` columns instead in `integer()`.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tanggapan', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Data tanggapan laporan
       $table->id('id_tanggapan');
       $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_pengaduan');
       $table->dateTime('tgl_tanggapan');
       $table->text('isi_tanggapan');
       $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_petugas');

       // Rekam tanggal
       $table->timestamps();

       // Menghubungkan kolom
       $table->foreign('id_pengaduan')->references('id_pengaduan')->on('pengaduan');
       $table->foreign('id_petugas')->references('id_petugas')->on('petugas');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I replace with unsignedBigInteger('id_pengaduan', 11); it still error, but when I remove length to just unsignedBigInteger('id_pengaduan'); it solved.

Comment: Cool. I edited my answer. Feel free to mark it as the excepted answer if it solves your issue. :)